# Storing byte[] PBEKeySpec to a openshift gear behave differently?

Tags: postgresql, security, byte, openshift

---

If any one could giveme some pointers:
I have a KeySpec generated by PBEKeySpec:

```
KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), "SALTSALT".getBytes(), 20000, 160);
SecretKeyFactory f = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
byte[] encoded = f.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
```

The encoded byte[] variable is stored on a Postgres DB 9.x, this value on testing Environment works just fine, but when I deploy it to OpenShift gear, the byte[] generated by the PBEKeySpec does not return the same value (it should), comparing to the one that I stored on the DB, encodning problem maybe? any clue?

Corresponding log from the same password:
One other thing, the byte[] on OS, changes size from 20 to 39

```
Test environment, passwd stored on DB: [-87, 98, 56, 51,55, 99, 99, 100, 53, 56, 57, 52, 51, 54, 101, 100, 50, 98, 51, 51, 57, 100, 98, 54, 99, 51, 98, 56, 102, 50, 99, 50, 50, 98, 51, 51, 49, 57, 49] size 39
OpenShift gear, password from login: [-117, -12, -115, -38, -58, -100, -62, 70, -87, 98, -73, 114, -56, 115, -91, 5, 23, 44, 119, 21] size: 20
```

The full code:

```
public abstract class PasswordServiceImpl implements PasswordByteService {

private String ENCRIPT_ALGORITHM = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1";
private int ENCRYPT_DEVIRED_KEY_LENGTH = 160;
private int ENCRIPT_ITERATIONS = 20000;
private String SALT_ALGORITHM = "SHA1PRNG";


@Override
    public boolean authenticate(final String attemptedPassword, final byte[] encryptedPassword, final byte[] salt)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {

    byte[] encryptedAttemptedPassword = getEncryptedPassword(attemptedPassword, salt);

    return Arrays.equals(encryptedPassword, encryptedAttemptedPassword);
}


@Override
public byte[] getEncryptedPassword(final String password, byte[] salt)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {

    String algorithm = ENCRIPT_ALGORITHM;
    int derivedKeyLength = ENCRYPT_DEVIRED_KEY_LENGTH;
    int iterations = ENCRIPT_ITERATIONS;

    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, iterations, derivedKeyLength);

    SecretKeyFactory f = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
    byte[] encoded = f.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();


    return encoded;
}


@Override
public byte[] generateSalt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException {
    SecureRandom random;
        random = SecureRandom.getInstance(SALT_ALGORITHM,"SUN");

    byte[] salt = new byte[8];
    random.nextBytes(salt);

    return salt;
}

}
```

Storing the user, via entityManager, hibernate.
The Entity

```
@Entity
public class UserData implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

...

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column
private byte[] password;


...
```

Configuration Class

```
@Stateless
public class ConfigurationBean implements Configuration {
...
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "primary")
private EntityManager em;
...

private void populateFailSafeUser(){

        try {
            PasswordService pws = new PasswordServiceImpl();
            byte[] salt = pws.generateSalt();
            byte[] encryptedPassword = pws.getEncryptedPassword(Values.FAILSAFE_USER_PASS, salt);

            UserData failsafeUser = new UserData(Values.FAILSAFE_USER_NAME, encryptedPassword, salt );

            em.persist(failsafeUser);
            em.flush();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException ex) {
            LOGGER.error(Msg.ERROR_ENCRIPTION_SERVICES);
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
            LOGGER.error(Msg.ERROR_ENCRIPTION_SERVICES + " proveedor de seguridad no encontrado!");
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not a PostgreSQL expert, but could it be the difference between a 32-bit and 64-bit operating system?

Comment: Checked out some javax.security forums, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I've created a CentOS 32 bit VM and tryed again, with no result, the PBEKeySpec does not retun the same value.

Comment: Are you saying that `f.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded()` returns something different in your testing enviornment than it does on OpenShift? Or that the value returned from the OpenShift database is not the same as the value you put in?

Comment: Yes, I call f.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded() and get the byte[] is stored on the DB (encryptedPassword), then when I try to login I call it again with the attempedPassword (the same that I used to store the first time) and when I try to compare them, they're not the same! I use Arrays.equals(a1,a2) to compare the byte[]'s

Comment: @nicoLinjava Can you show the code that *stores* the byte[] in the database and the code that *retrieves* it from the database?

Comment: Also, you might consider encoding the byte[] as hex or base64 before storing it in the DB. Technically it's not quite as efficient, but it can be easier to debug.

Comment: I've done some further tests: and when I store the byte[] encryptedPassword into Postgres

Comment: further tests: the byte[] encryptedPassword into Postgres is ok, the f.generateSecret().getEncoded() changes it's byte[] value?, meaning: "hellohello" as byte[] = [89,100,100,..] legnth 20, but when I call once more after the value is stored into the DB the value byte[] changes (same value "hellohello") to something like [-12,30,60,...] and changes aslo the length of the second one to random length 38 or 69, what is really strange is that the algorithm works fine on LinuxMint 64 bit, and centos 32 bits, but can it be something about openshift cloud infraestructure? BTW Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've posted, it doesn't look like you're storing the salt in the database. You need to store the generated salt that you use when encrypting the password. You then need to use that same salt from the database when authenticating the password entered by the user.

**Update**
If you are indeed using the exact same salt both when generating the original encrypted password and generating the attempted password for authentication, and getting different values back from `f.generateSecret(spec)`, then my best guess is that there's some sort of bug on OpenShift. Especially if it works for you locally with the exact same code.

I recommend making as small of an example as possible to reproduce the problem, and [opening a bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/describecomponents.cgi?product=OpenShift%20Origin) with OpenShift. Try to leave Postgres out of it; if you're sure you're getting the same thing back from Postgres as what you put in originally, then it's not part of the problem.

Comment: Checked! the salt it's stored ok, UserData failsafeUser = new UserData(Values.FAILSAFE_USER_NAME, encryptedPassword, salt ); The salt it's stored fine, I double checked it.

Comment: And yes! the same Salt it's used for storing the encruptedpasswd and the attempedPassword.